# class Tk has no attribute 'Frame'

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

an attribute error occurs when I run a simple Tkinter program. I've checked the tutorial and related questions but I still don't know how to fix it.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
class Application(Tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.createWidgets()

def createWidgets(self):
    self.quitButton = Tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
                                command=self.quit)
    self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

The error message showing:

```
class Application(Tk.Frame):
AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'Frame'
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: improve your indentation

Comment: Do you have any file called Tkinter.py or similar?

Answer (score 0):

you never pass a tk window to the application

```
import Tkinter # careful with importing it as Tk because Tk is already a sub module of Tkinter 
class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit',
                                command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

window = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(master=window)
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```